# ASP.NET MVC Preflight (OPTIONS) requests handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors

I want to use CORS with multiple sources for my web application but I am stuck now. It worked with the first source because I set the `Allow-Origin` header from `Web.config`. But now I want to do it programmatically to change the header based on the `Origin`/`Referer`.

- won't work in browsers like Chrome.

I created the `Application_BeginRequest` in `Global.asax`. Problem is...it is only triggered for `GET`/`POST` requests but not for the `OPTIONS` call.
Second option to add OnActionExecuting in a global filter. Same problem. `OPTIONS` requests don't trigger this method.

Any idea what is going around here?

I am using .NET Framework 4.8.

Code:

```
    public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly string NEEDS_CUSTOM_ORIGIN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomOrigin"]?.ConnectionString ?? "";

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                // IT NEVER HITS THIS OR ANY OTHER PART OF THIS METHOD FOR OPTIONS
            }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NEEDS_CUSTOM_ORIGIN))
            {
                var originHeader = "";
                if (((IList)filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.AllKeys).Contains("Origin"))
                {
                    originHeader = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Origin"];
                }
                else if (((IList)filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.AllKeys).Contains("Referer"))
                {
                    originHeader = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originHeader))
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Global.asax:
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                 // NEVER
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not simply use [.NET's CORS middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? No need to re-invent the wheel, unless you're planning to improve the official middleware.

Comment: @jub0bs because I am not using .NET Core, it is the .NET Framework 4.8 MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Well...after a few hours of digging I finally found the answer by comparing it with another project that seemed to work when adding the code above in it.

The fix in Web.config is the following and it looks like IIS is eager to handle the OPTIONS requests, so we need to remove the OPTIONSVerbHandler and then ours (the one from Application_BeginRequest) will be considered.

```
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

And final code:

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                var originHeader = "";
                if (((IList)Request.Headers.AllKeys).Contains("Origin"))
                {
                    originHeader = Request.Headers["Origin"];
                }
                else if (((IList)Request.Headers.AllKeys).Contains("Referer"))
                {
                    originHeader = Request.Headers["Referer"];
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originHeader))
                {
                    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
                }

                if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                {
                    Response.Flush();
                }
        }
```